# Unable to convert the tensorflow model to tflite

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

Input size of the tensor does not matching the output size of the tensor

I have executed the following in command prompt

```
tflite_convert /
 --output_file=C:\Users\TS-PC04\Desktop\toutput.tflite /
--graph_def_file=C:\Users\TS-PC04\Desktop\t.pb /
 --input_shape=1,513,513,3 /
 --input_arrays=ImageTensor /
 --output_arrays=SemanticPredictions
```

The error I am getting is
Check failed: input_shape.dims().size() == op->size.size() (4 vs. 3).

Comment: The input shape must be expressed as a list and not a string.

Comment: I changed it but showing the same error

Comment: No, it should be `[1,513,513,3]`.

Comment: It should not be list see this [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/23747). Also it is not taking as the list giving error as  ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[1'

Comment: You could try to omit the `--input_shape` altogether. But most likely, the converter expects `--input_shape=513,513,3`.

Comment: @AlexCohn If I omit --input_shape then `ValueError: None is only supported in the 1st dimension. Tensor 'ImageTensor' has invalid shape '[1, None, None, 3]'.`If I give input_shape=513,513,3 then `ValueError: The shape of tensor 'ImageTensor' cannot be changed from (1, ?, ?, 3) to [513, 513, 3]. Shapes must be equal rank, but are 4 and 3 `

Comment: Have you tried to add `--output_shapes=...` as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pip install --upgrade tensorflow`.
This works for me and I am successfully converting .pb to .tflite